# Android jni UnsatisfiedLinkError wrong function name

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

`03-02 16:19:35.302 12503-12503/com.aa.bb E/CrashReport: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.AAA.livestudio.recording.camera.preview.RecordingPreviewScheduler.notifyFrameAvailable() (tried Java_com_AAA_livestudio_recording_camera_previfw_RecordingPreviewScheduler_notifyFrameAvailable and Java_com_AAA_livestudio_recording_camera_preview_RecordingPreviewScheduler_notifyFrameAvailable__)`

I met a weired problem, When I open a Activity, crashes happened above,

where is the word "previfw" from? I just has a name "preview"

I make sure that I *never* had this guy in Java or C++

Now I suspect may be memory leak or memery insufficy

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that it does not find the JNI function for

```
native void com.AAA.livestudio.recording.camera.preview.RecordingPreviewScheduler.notifyFrameAvailable()
```

You should check your JNI code to see if your C/C++ code provides the function:

```
extern "C" void Java_com_AAA_livestudio_recording_camera_preview_RecordingPreviewScheduler_notifyFrameAvailable(xxx)
```

Do not forget `extern "C"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you tell me  what is previfw ?

Comment: I make sure I have extern C "" and this function exist

Comment: Then check if the library is loaded or not.

Comment: After Application create I load this so.

Comment: I mean, you should check if the `.so` **really** exist in your android device.

Comment: Of course it exists, because sometimes this can work, sometimes it crashes